# How to implement a trait for all numeric types (including references) with a single macro instead of using generics?

Tags: rust

I try to implement a trait for the following types: `i32`, `&i32`, `&mut i32`, `std::num::NonZeroI32` without using generics. I therefore use a macro, but I'd like not to duplicate the code.

I cannot find a formula that allows to transform all those types to a mere `i32`.

My attempt:

```
use std::borrow::Borrow;

trait Foo {
    fn foo(self);
}

macro_rules! impl_foo {
    ( $t0:ty as $t:ty ) => {
        impl Foo for $t0 {
            fn foo(self) {
                let _ = <$t>::from(*(self.borrow()));
            }
        }
    }
}

impl_foo!(i32 as i32);
impl_foo!(std::num::NonZeroI32 as i32);
impl_foo!(&'_ i32 as i32);
impl_foo!(&'_ mut i32 as i32);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine `clone` and `into` to support references and simple conversions together.

```
macro_rules! impl_foo {
    ( $t0:ty as $t:ty ) => {
        impl Foo for $t0 {
            fn foo(self) {
                let _: $t = self.clone().into();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`Clone::clone` will be a no-op on a value, and will reveal the underlying type if it is a reference. The result of `clone()` is unambiguous, so the input type to `into()` will be inferred unambiguously too.

For simple `Copy` types, you should expect `clone` to be implemented as a `memcpy` in most cases, so this shouldn't be a performance concern.